# Limit on inner join per parent

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

I have a table named `weathers`:

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| id     | temp  | id_freg |
+--------+-------+---------+
|    337 | 12.36 |       1 |
|   3556 | 11.46 |       2 |
|   6775 |  9.30 |       3 |
|  10210 |  8.55 |       1 |
|  13429 |  9.69 |       2 |
```

And a table named `freguesias` (small places in portugal):

```
+----+-----------+
| id | name      |
+----+-----------+
|  1 | Cabeção   |
|  2 | Pavia     |
|  3 | Brotas    |
|  4 | Mora      |
```

What I need from here is to do an INNER join and limit the the number of weathers results per `freguesia`, so if I want the weather for 3 `freguesias` I want to `order desc limit 1` for each, in other words you can say that is the current weather for each `freguesias` in the `where` clause.

My query at this moment is:

```
select weathers.* 
from weathers 
inner join freguesias 
    ON weathers.id_freg = freguesias.id 
where weathers.id_freg IN (2,1) 
LIMIT 1;
```

Well this doesn't work since I need one result for each: one for `id_freg = 1`, and another for `id_freg = 2`, each one ordered by `weathers.id DESC`

Comment: It might make your question clearer to include sample results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `weathers.id` specifies the most recent value, then you can calculate the most recent value for each freguensia.  In this case I would recommend a correlated subquery:

```
select w.* 
from weathers w
where w.id_freg in (2, 1) and
      w.id = (select max(w2.id) 
              from weathers w2 
              where w2.id_freg = w.id_freg
             );
```

You want an index on `weathers(id_freq, id)` for performance.

Comment: it should be =>> select max(w2.id) from weathers w2 where w2.id_freg = w.id_freg

Comment: Is the `weathers w` same as `weathers as w`?

Comment: @HulaHula . . . Yes.  I use `as` always for column aliases and never for table aliases.

Answer (score 1):

I've setup a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0636e4/11) to show how this might be done. Since you are essentially producing a list of the locations, I've based the query on that table, and joined to the temperature measurements. I presume you want the most recent (last inserted) row for each city.

```
select * 
from freguesias f
join (
    SELECT w.id_freg,MAX(w.id) as id
    FROM weathers w
    GROUP BY w.id_freg
    ORDER BY w.id DESC) as wf
  ON wf.id_freg = f.id
JOIN weathers w1
  ON w1.id = wf.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0636e4/11/0)**:

```
| id |    name | id_freg |    id |    id | temp | id_freg |
|----|---------|---------|-------|-------|------|---------|
|  1 | Cabeção |       1 | 10210 | 10210 | 8.55 |       1 |
|  2 |   Pavia |       2 | 13429 | 13429 | 9.69 |       2 |
|  3 |  Brotas |       3 |  6775 |  6775 |  9.3 |       3 |
```

Comment: you are missing column w.temp in your subquery ....and your query will work only for mysql

Comment: The subquery doesn't need temp since it is only there to identify the most recent rows in the temperatures table. The next join gets the temp. Also, this was tagged as MySQL, so I've provided a MySQL solution