# Translate sql raw query into eloquent relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

This is a follow up question from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921277/limit-on-inner-join-per-parent/49921488).

County model:

```
...
public function freguesias() {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Freguesia::class, 'id_county');
}
...
```

Now basically I have on my Freguesia Model:

```
...
public function county() {
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\County::class, 'id_county');
}

public function weathers() {
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Weather::class, 'id_freg');
}
...
```

And I am eager loading this relations from county, e.g:

```
$item = County::with(['freguesias' => function($q) {
    $q->with(['weathers']);
}])->select(['id'])->findOrfail(request()->id);
```

My main problem with this is that I have to collect (last inserted row in weathers table with `id_freg = X`) the current weather for each `Freguesia` that belongs to a specific `County`. `where weathers.id_freg IN (X, Y, Z) ordered by id DESC`

My weathers table looks like:

```
+--------+-------+---------+
| id     | temp  | id_freg |
+--------+-------+---------+
|    337 | 12.36 |       1 |
|   3556 | 11.46 |       2 |
|   6775 |  9.30 |       3 |
|  10210 |  8.55 |       1 |
|  13429 |  9.69 |       2 |
```

I [have already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49921277/limit-on-inner-join-per-parent/49921488#49921488) the correct SQL for this:

```
select w.* 
from weathers w
where w.id_freg in (X, Y, ...) and
      w.id = (select max(w2.id) 
              from weathers w2 
              where w2.id_freg = w.id_freg
             );
```

But how can I implement this in the eager loading? Or is there other way through County Model maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest solution is using an ordered `HasOne` relationship:

```php
public function weather() {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Weather::class, 'id_freg')->orderByDesc('id');
}
```

This works but fetches *all* weathers for the freguesias when used in eager loading.

The improved version using your query:

```php
public function weather() {
    return $this->hasOne(\App\Weather::class, 'id_freg')
        ->where('id', function($query) {
            $query->selectRaw('max(id)')
                ->from('weathers as w2')
                ->where('w2.id_freg', DB::raw('weathers.id_freg'));
        });
}
```